# Psr-4 Autoloader is referencing incorrect Class Path

Tags: php, namespaces

I created Autoloader with Composer:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {

            "Init\\": "App/Controllers/"
        }
    }
}
```

**with these folder structure:**
App/Controllers/{Classes}

But my User Class was showing: "Init\Users" instead of "Init\Controllers\Users"

Here's how I wrote it on my view page:

`namespace Init; $user = new Users(); $user->create();`

Comment: When you say `new Users` without any additional qualification, it is in the current namespace, thus `Init\Users`. You can either qualify it fully as `new \Init\Controllers\Users`,  or use a similar `use` statement. This really isn’t a PSR or composer thing, either, just how PHP name resolution works

Comment: @ChrisHaas -- Thank you. I tried this **new \Init\Controllers\Users;** but it was showing: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "App\Controllers\Users" not found. But I have the Users Classs inside **Init/Controllers/{Users.class}** folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `controllers` from your path. The autoloader automatically parse the inner folders to the base namespace.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Init\\": "App/Controllers/" 
            //Returns Init\Users;
...
            "Init\\": "App/" //Returns Init\Controllers\Users 
            // (If users class is in Controllers folder);
        }
    }
}
```